# Kivy: get parent inside widget which is added in python

Tags: python, kivy

How do I get the reference to a parent inside a widget that is not added by kvlang but in python.
Normally you would just call `self.parent` however that returns `Null` if the widget is added in python to the parent.

An example:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock

kvlang = '''
<ScreenManagement>:
    ScreenOne:

<ScreenOne>:
    name: 'First'


<ScreenTwo>:
    name: 'Second'

'''


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        def setup(*args):
            self.add_widget(ScreenTwo())    #add ScreenTwo later in python

        Clock.schedule_once(setup)

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        def setup(*args):
            print("Parent of ScreenOne: {}".format(self.parent))        #this is working
        Clock.schedule_once(setup)

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        def setup(*args):
            print("Parent of ScreenTwo: {}".format(self.parent))        #this is not working, self.parent will return None
        Clock.schedule_once(setup)



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kvlang)
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This will return:

```
Parent of ScreenOne: <__main__.ScreenManagement object at 0x7f98a3fddb40>
Parent of ScreenTwo: None
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this? perhaps a little bit more of a context will help more

Comment: I would like to access variables from the parent class, of course I could pass them as arguments in the instantiation of the child as well, but I was wondering why this is not possible what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Widgets added with `add_widget` actually has a valid reference to their parent:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
<ScreenTwo>
    Label:
        text: 'Hello, world'    
''')

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        screen = ScreenTwo()

        print(screen.parent)
        self.add_widget(screen)  
        print(screen.parent)


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def on_touch_down(self, *args):
        print(self.parent)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

It's just not available in their `__init__` method.

Comment: Hmm, do you have any clue why not? The workaround I can think of seems a bit clumsy: `parent = sys._getframe().f_back.f_locals['self']`

Comment: @Sebastian `parent` property isn't instantiated when you create a widget because there's no way of telling what will you do will it or whether it will have any parent at all. Only after you add this widget to some hierarchy it can be set to a reasonable value. Anyway, if all you want to do is do some initialization in a widget using parent variables then you can just define `on_parent(self, screen, parent)` method and move the code there. This will be called as soon as this property becomes valid and you can access the parent using `parent` argument .