# Stuck with Class Function in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

So I 've been creating this Kivy App, but this happened

```
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        '''conn = sqlite3.connect('first_db.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
        screens = c.fetchall()
        for i in range(len(screens)):
            self.add_note()
        c.close()'''
        self.add_note()
    def add_note(self, name = ""):
        self.add_widget(NoteScreen(name = name))
        print(self.parent)
```

my .kv file

```
    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height
        size_hint_y: 1.0 - toolbar.height/root.height

        MyScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            NoteScreen:
                name: "Home"
```

When I run the app, instead of printing out the parent of MyScreenManager which is MDNavigationLayout, it printed out "None". I don't know how to fix it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kivy: get parent inside widget which is added in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396372/kivy-get-parent-inside-widget-which-is-added-in-python)

Comment: I don't think so since MDNavigationLayout is already the parent of MyScreenManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.parent` isn't available at the time of the `__init__` method because the class is first instantiated, then added to its parent.

Per [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.parent):

> The parent of a widget is set when the widget is added to another widget

The base `Widget.__init_()` doesn't set `self.parent`.

Since Kivy uses an observable [property](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html) for `parent` the action can be added in `on_parent`

```
def on_parent(self, instance, value):
    super(MyScreenManager, self).on_parent(instance, value)
    self.add_note()
```

Comment: Oh ok. Can you recommend any way to get around this? I want to use a function from another parent class right when the class is first instantiated. I'm still a beginner

Comment: @BachTran see update